# Python return extra value from decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I have some functions and I want to do some computation based on the argument values passed to it in a decorator. I am able to achieve this but the decorator populates an important object which I would like to reuse later on. eg..

```
def my_awesome_decorator(*d):
    how_do_i_return_this_object_which_got_created_here
    def wrapping_function(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ...
        return wrapper
    return wrapping_function


class A:
    @my_awesome_decorator(d)
    def fun(a, b, c):
        ...
```

I want the object to be easily accessible using `object_A.how_do_i_return_this_object_which_got_created_here`

Answer (score 1):

This is not something a decorator can do. All that a decorator can do is return something different for the given function object. You don't have a choice what the return value is assigned to, in the namespace.

Better options are:

- using an attribute on the decorated function:

  ```
  def my_awesome_decorator(*d):
      def wrapping_function(func):
          def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
              # ...
          wrapper.some_attribute = ...
          return wrapper
      return wrapping_function
  ```

  after which `ClassObject.methodname.some_attribute` and `instance.methodname.some_attribute` are available.
- For Python 3.6 or newer, you can add a `__init_subclass__` method to a baseclass for your classes. It could combine with an attribute set by your decorator to copy an attribute over to the class:

  ```
  class BaseClass:
      def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
          super().__init_subclass__()
          special = None
          for attr in vars(cls).values():
              special = getattr(attr, '_special_attribute_name', None)
              if special is not None:
                  break
          cls.target_attribute = special
  ```

  after which subclasses will copy across the first `method._special_attribute_name` attribute that is found to the class object; a decorator can set that attribute on a method.
- For earlier Python versions, use a metaclass to do the same:

  ```
  class SomeMetaClass(type):
      def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds):
          special = None
          for attr in namespace.values():
              special = getattr(attr, '_special_attribute_name', None)
              if special is not None:
                  break
          namespace['target_attribute'] = special
          return super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace, **kwds)
  ```

Comment: Why not receive self (class instance) as an argument of the decorator function?

Comment: @Rohi: because decorators don't operate on bound methods. There is nothing to assign to `self` when a decorator is called, *because there is not even a class yet*.

Comment: @Rohi: the *wrapper* returned by the decorator later on will be bound, and `self` passed in when called, but that's only after you already created an instance, and then referenced the method and called it. The attribute on the class might be needed way earlier than that.

Comment: If the instance is already created beforehand then the solution should work, might be viable for the OP

Comment: @Rohi: how would you create an instance for a class that is not yet defined? Decorators are called when the functions are created. The functions are created before the class object is created.